# Add link at the end of wp_nav_menu

Tags: menus

I need to add a conditional menu item such as "/at" or "/de" or "/ch" in the `wp_nav_menu`. Since the link is conditional (based on the country the website is being viewed), it can't be added from the backend but instead has to be hardcoded.

How do I add this new conditional link at the end of what the `wp_nav_menu` is populating? Thank you.

Comment: I see this is what I want.. http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-custom-items-to-specific-wordpress-menus/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what worked for me (based on [this](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-custom-items-to-specific-wordpress-menus/)).. hope it will be helpful for others too..

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items','primary_navigation', 10, 2 );
function primary_navigation( $items, $args ) {
    if( $args->theme_location == 'primary_navigation' )  {
        if ( ! isset( $_SESSION['menu_country'] ) ) {
            $country = json_decode( file_get_contents(
               "http://freegeoip.net/json/" . esc_url( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] )
            ) );

            $_SESSION['menu_country'] = strtolower( $country->country_code );   
        }

       $items .=  '<li class="menu-produkte"><a href="/' .
          esc_url( $_SESSION['menu_country'] ) .'/shop">Produkte</a></li>';
    }
    return $items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also potentially do this with `items_wrap` if you wanted to. Haven't tested this, but maybe something like:

```
if ( !isset( $_SESSION['menu_country'] ) ) {
    $country = json_decode( file_get_contents(
     "http://freegeoip.net/json/" . esc_url( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] )
    ) );

    $_SESSION['menu_country'] = strtolower( $country->country_code );

    $item = '<li class="menu-produkte"><a href="/' .
        esc_url( $_SESSION['menu_country'] ) . '/shop">Produkte</a></li>';
}
else {
    $item = null;
}
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s' . $item . '</ul>',
) );
```